# Python Encapsulate a function to Print to a variable

Tags: python

If I have a function that contains a lot of print statements:

ie.

```
def funA():
  print "Hi"
  print "There"
  print "Friend"
  print "!"
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
def main():
  ##funA() does not print to screen here
  a = getPrint(funA()) ##where getPrint is some made up function/object
  print a ##prints what funA would normally print at this step
```

So when funcA gets called it doesn't do any printing, instead it output to an object. I then print the object to get the result. Is there a way of doing this? I also do not want to touch the original function.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do *almost* exactly what you want, as long as you don't mind a tiny syntax difference:

```
import cStringIO
import sys

def getPrint(thefun, *a, **k):
  savstdout = sys.stdout
  sys.stdout = cStringIO.StringIO()
  try:
    thefun(*a, **k)
  finally:
    v = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    sys.stdout = savstdout
  return v
```

The tiny difference is that you must call `getPrint(funA)`, **not** `getPrint(funA())` -- i.e., you must pass the function object itself, **without** the trailing parentheses that would call it immediately, *before* `getPrint` can do its magic.

If you absolutely insist on those extra parentheses, then `getPrint` cannot do **all** the needed preparation, and must be supplemented by other code to prepare things right (I strongly recommend losing the extra parentheses, thus enabling the encapsulation of all the functionality inside `getPrint`!).

Comment: +1.  I would use sys.__stdout__, which officially contains the original sys.stdout.  There is no need to save the original sys.stdout in savstdout, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @EOL, if you're running your code under IDLE or other GUI-based IDE, "the original stdout" may be useless or unusable (e.g. it may be closed, directed to a non-existing terminal, etc); and there IS most definitely a need to save and restore `sys.stdout` in order to put the IDE back to a usable state when `getPrint` is gone.

Comment: Why are you calling the cStringIO module?

Answer (score 3):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

def getPrint(func, *args, **kwds):
  old_stdout = sys.stdout
  sys.stdout = StringIO()
  try:
    func(*args, **kwds)
  except:
    raise
  else:
    return sys.stdout.getvalue()
  finally:
    sys.stdout = old_stdout

#...
a = getPrint(funA) # notice no (), it is called by getPrint
print a.rstrip("\n") # avoid extra trailing lines
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to do a context manager

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import StringIO
import sys

@contextmanager
def capture():
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
    try:
        yield sys.stdout
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Now you can run any printing code:

```
with capture() as c:
    funA()
    funB()
    print 'HELLO!'
```

then later:

```
print c.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sys.stdout` with a [file-like object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Answer (score 1):

Use cStringIO ( see [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) ).

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

getPrint( funA() )
# use mystdout to get string
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to change your `funA()` to not print anything, but simply to return the string values.

Like so:

```
def funA():
    return "Hi\n" + "There\n" + "Friend\n" + "!\n"

# later:
print(funA())
```

It's always easy to collect strings and print them; it's tricker to to collect strings as they are being printed.

If you have a huge body of existing printing functions, then yeah, use one of the tricks provided here to collect the output.

Comment: the problem lies in the fact that the function is not trivial as the one I posted. It calls upon other functions that calls upon other functions that does the printing.

Comment: Well, you have two choices.  If all the functions use a common single function to emit their output, then hook that one function and you can capture all the output; otherwise (maybe they all use the Python 2.x print *statement* which you can't really hook) then you will want to use one of the tricks documented on this page.