# Python: storing print output from different module's function

Tags: python

I'm trying to store the print output from a function of another module imported,
as a string and write it into a file. However, that function does not return a string, it only prints the output.
so I need something like:

```
import someModule
......
f.open('test.v','w')
out = storetheprintoutputasstring(someModule.main())
f.write(out)
f.close
```

How do I do this?
Please help me out and thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer

Comment: If you are working on a Unix based OS, simply use output redirection. `$python someModule.py > output_file.txt`

If not, then you'll want to read in from stdout and write to your file. 

I'm operating under the assumption that you don't need to have this done dynamically.

Comment: I need this to be done within the python file, not on the shell..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're asking to do is a bit of a hack, so I assume you *have* to do it this way.

Here is how you could redirect `stdout` to a file using the `with` statement:

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def redirected(stdout):
    saved_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open(stdout, 'w')
    yield
    sys.stdout = saved_stdout

with redirected(stdout='file.txt'):
    print 'Hello'
print 'Hello again'
```

Comment: I would add `try: yield; finally:...`.

Answer (score 2):

mod1.py:

```
def main():
    print "BOHOO"
```

mod2.py:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO
import mod1

def storetheprintoutputasstring(func):
    saved_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
    func()   # Call function
    sys.stdout = saved_stdout
    return mystdout.getvalue()

f = open('test.v','w')
out = storetheprintoutputasstring(mod1.main)
f.write(out)
f.close()
```

Run **python mod2.py**.

test.v contains:

```
BOHOO
```