# Get the results of dis.dis() in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare the bytecode of two things with difflib, but dis.dis() always prints it to the console. Any way to get the output in a string?

Comment: If anyone gets here and is looking for a Python 2 solution, see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12111717/3004881).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uses `StringIO` to redirect `stdout` to a string-like object (python 2.7 solution)

```
import sys
import StringIO
import dis

def a():
    print "Hello World"

stdout = sys.stdout # Hold onto the stdout handle
f = StringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = f # Assign new stdout

dis.dis(a) # Run dis.dis()

sys.stdout = stdout # Reattach stdout

print f.getvalue() # print contents
```

Comment: I like this. It is dynamic.

Comment: For redirecting `sys.stdout`, better use https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Python 3.4 or later, you can get that string by using the method [`Bytecode.dis()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Bytecode.dis):

```
>>> s = dis.Bytecode(lambda x: x + 1).dis()
>>> print(s)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

You also might want to take a look at [`dis.get_instructions()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.get_instructions), which returns an iterator of named tuples, each corresponding to a bytecode instruction.

Comment: While the other one might be more inspiring, **this** should be the accepted answer.