# Redirecting the output of a python function from STDOUT to variable in Python

Tags: python, io-redirection

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
def fun():
    runner = InteractiveConsole()
    while(True):
        code = raw_input()
        code.rstrip('\n')
        # I want to achieve the following
        # By default the output and error of the 'code' is sent to STDOUT and STDERR
        # I want to obtain the output in two variables out and err
        out,err = runner.push(code)
```

All the solution that I have looked at till now, use either pipes to issue separate script execution command (which is not possible in my case). Any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK the output can only be sent to an object which has a `write()` method on it, so you can create a class which contains a `write` method and make `out` an instance of it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary write() is just for writing data to stderr stream. What about the data sent to stdout.

Comment: `print()` can help you `print("something",file=out)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1218933/222914)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: OP is using python 2.x, so `print >> out, "something"` instead

Answer (score 8):

```
import StringIO, sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def redirected(out=sys.stdout, err=sys.stderr):
    saved = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
    sys.stdout, sys.stderr = out, err
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = saved


def fun():
    runner = InteractiveConsole()
    while True:
        out = StringIO.StringIO()
        err = StringIO.StringIO()
        with redirected(out=out, err=err):
            out.flush()
            err.flush()
            code = raw_input()
            code.rstrip('\n')
            # I want to achieve the following
            # By default the output and error of the 'code' is sent to STDOUT and STDERR
            # I want to obtain the output in two variables out and err
            runner.push(code)
            output = out.getvalue()
        print output
```

In newer versions of python, this contezt manager is built in:

```
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(out), contextlib.redirect_stderr(err):
    ...
```

Comment: You can also recover them from `sys.__stdout__` and `sys.__stderr__`, so no need of `saved`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That fails if I nest two redirects

Comment: @Eric I have a doubt. In your approach, the vaiable output records the output received till now. Is there a way I can obtain the output just from the current function call.

Comment: `sys.stdout` also has `.encoding` but `StringIO` does not have that (and other attributes. If the code inside `redirected`  relies on those attributes it will fail. Otherwise nice solution

Comment: It should be `import io` instead of `import StringIO` I guess (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/io.html#io.StringIO) - even for 2.7 code). Then `StringIO.StringIO()` becomes `io.StringIO()`.

Answer (score 1):

[InteractiveConsole](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html#interactive-console-objects) doesn't expose any API for setting a file like object for output or errors, you'll need to [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`. As always with monkey patching, be mindful of what the side effects might be. In this case, you'd be replacing the global stdin and stdout file objects with your own implementation, which might swallow up unintended output as well (especially if you're using any threads).

It would be slightly safer to 'tee' the output with something like:

```
import sys
import StringIO


class TeeBuffer(object):

    def __init__(self, real):
        self.real = real
        self.buf = StringIO.StringIO()

    def write(self, val):
        self.real.write(val)
        self.buf.write(val)


def fun():
    runner = InteractiveConsole()

    out = TeeBuffer(sys.stdout)
    err = TeeBuffer(sys.stderr)

    sys.stdout = out
    sys.stderr = err

    while(True):
        code = raw_input()
        code.rstrip('\n')

        out, err = runner.push(code)
        outstr = out.buf.getvalue()
        errstr = err.buf.getvalue()

    sys.stdout = out.real
    sys.stderr = err.real
```

Then your user still sees the output, without you having to worry about printing it back out to the correct place on each run.

Comment: That's not really monkeypatching... Monkeypatching would be modifying the write method of the builtin stdout.

Comment: It's monkey patching the `stdout` field of the `sys` object with a different representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a context manager to [redirect stdout temporarily](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

> ```
> @contextmanager
> def stdout_redirected(new_stdout):
>     save_stdout = sys.stdout
>     sys.stdout = new_stdout
>     try:
>         yield None
>     finally:
>         sys.stdout = save_stdout
> ```
>
> Used as follows:
>
> ```
> with opened(filename, "w") as f:
>     with stdout_redirected(f):
>         print "Hello world"
> ```
>
> This isn't thread-safe, of course, but neither is doing this same dance manually. In single-threaded programs (for example, in scripts) it is a popular way of doing things.

---

It's easy to tweak this to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `cStringIO`s:

```
@contextmanager
def out_redirected():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    save_stderr = sys.stderr
    sys.stdout = cStringIO.String()
    sys.stderr = cStringIO.String()
    try:
        yield sys.stdout, sys.stderr
    finally:
        sys.stdout = save_stdout
        sys.stderr = save_stderr
```

You'd use this as

```
with out_redirected() as out, err:
    runner.push(code)
    out.seek(0)
    print out.read()
```