# How can I redirect print output of a function in python

Tags: python, function, printing, stdout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

I have a function in python that prints something to the standard output

```
def foo():
    print("some text")
```

I want to 'redirect' the text that is being printed in this function into a variable, i.e. 'wrap' this function or whatever so that the text is stored in a variable:

```
text = wrapper(foo)
```

Is there a robust way to temporarily change `sys.stdout` or to open a variable as a `FileObject`, or something else?

Comment: Why not simply use your own print function?

Comment: The function definition is given, I cannot the function itself.

Comment: Do we assume that you can't modify the function and just change the print to a `return`? And that you wish to temporarily modify `sys.stdout` during the function (ie decorate it) to capture it?

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate- it offers the solution of redirecting `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` object.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? In 3 you can just redefine `print`...

Comment: @David: I think the link you pointed out is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @phant0m -- Sometimes you don't actually have access to the function like that.  `dis.dis` is one which prints to stdout in the standard library.

Comment: @mgilson Sure, but it was unclear from his problem description whether such a simplistic solution would have been enough.

Answer (score 22):

For python3.4+, there's a context manager for this in the standard library.

```
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file_like_object):
    ...
```

---

*This part of the answer was updated, but is mostly for people who are still stuck in a python2.x world*

If you're stuck on an older version of python, this context manager isn't too hard to write yourself.  The key is that you can update `sys.stdout` to whatever file-like object you want (that's what `print` writes to):

```
>>> import sys
>>> import StringIO
>>> stdout = sys.stdout  # keep a handle on the real standard output
>>> sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO() # Choose a file-like object to write to
>>> foo() 
>>> sys.stdout = stdout
>>> foo()
bar
```

To create a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to set stdout to whatever you want when you enter the context and then have the context manager reset stdout when you `__exit__` the context.

Here's a simple example using `contextlib` to create the context manager:

```
import contextlib
import sys

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout_redirect(where):
    sys.stdout = where
    try:
        yield where
    finally:
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

def foo():
    print 'bar'

# Examples with StringIO
import StringIO

with stdout_redirect(StringIO.StringIO()) as new_stdout:
    foo()

new_stdout.seek(0)
print "data from new_stdout:",new_stdout.read()

new_stdout1 = StringIO.StringIO()
with stdout_redirect(new_stdout1):
    foo()

new_stdout1.seek(0)
print "data from new_stdout1:",new_stdout1.read()

# Now with a file object:
with open('new_stdout') as f:
    with stdout_redirect(f):
        foo()

# Just to prove that we actually did put stdout back as we were supposed to
print "Now calling foo without context"
foo()
```

Note:

On python3.x, `StringIO.StringIO` has moved to `io.StringIO`.  Also, on python2.x, `cStringIO.StringIO` might be slightly more performant.

Comment: +1 for the context manager suggestion, which would probably be the cleanest approach.

Comment: @l4mpi: see "Redirect stdout temporarily" in [PEP 0343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). There's some other examples there that may interest you.

Comment: From Python 3.4 `contextlib.redirect_stdout()` is available as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434594/848277 Here's an answer for folks using Python 3.X since the above wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3.x, you can just redefine `print`.

```
B = []

def print(str):
    global B
    B.append(str)

def A():
    print("example")

A()

>>> B
['example']
```

If, for some reason, you need the built-in print back, just do:

```
from builtins import print
```