# Python - reset stdout to normal, after previously redirecting it to a file

Tags: python, stdout

At the beginning of my python program I have the following line:

```
sys.stdout = open('stdout_file', 'w')
```

Halfway through my program I would like to set stdout back to the normal stdout.  How do I do this?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197009/how-can-i-redirect-print-output-of-a-function-in-python/14197079#14197079

Comment: See also [How to capture stdout output from a Python function call? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call) for other options e.g. context manager.

Comment: See also [How to capture stdout output from a Python function call? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call) for other options e.g. context manager.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The original `stdout` can be accessed as `sys.__stdout__`.  This [is documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__stdin__).

Comment: I use this style (where there are no namespace conflicts) whenever I overload any module attribute. eg `io.__file__ = io.file; def io_file(*args, **kwargs): ... else return io.__file__(*args, **kwargs) ; io.file = io_file`

Comment: Hm, this is not helpful if I only overwrite one method of stderr though (`sys.stderr.write = logger.error` for example)

Comment: @xjcl: First, the question is asking about replacing stdout, not replacing individual methods on it.  Second, it's probably not a great idea to do that; instead just replace the whole object with a new one that has the method you want.  You can try it if you want but monkeypatching individual methods on objects isn't the kind of thing that's going to be supported to the same degree that replacing stream objects is.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me finish some code!

Answer (score 6):

Another common practice is to store the default stdout and / or stdin and then return them once you are finished with sending your output / input to custom streams.
For instance:

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('stdout_file', 'w')
sys.stdout = orig_stdout
```

Answer (score 5):

The same holds for stderr, of course. At the end, these lines are needed to get the original streams.

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

Answer (score 0):

open file and exchange sys variable with file variable

```
f = open("sample.txt", "w")

sys.stdout, f = f, sys.stdout
print("sample", flush=True)
```

and take it back

```
f, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, f
print("sample")
```