# Retrieve elements printed in console from read_gbq() Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

When using Pandas Google Big Query function `read_gbq()`, some nice information related to the query (size, number of rows...) is printed into the console. Is there a way to store this information in order to use it later on?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python. If not you should edit your question with more details and an example of code and console output

Comment: Also checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197079/4720935