# How to capture untrained-on values h2o python

Tags: python, h2o

How do you capture unknown values when making predictions on `h2o` data frames?

For example, when doing something like:

```
model.predict(frame_in)
```

in the h2o python api, a progress bar loads while the model is making predictions and then a series of lists are outputted detailing the unknown labels seen for each of the enum types of the model predictive features. Eg.

```
/home/mapr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/job.py:69: UserWarning:
Test/Validation dataset column 'feature1' has levels not trained on: [, <values>]
```

Is there any way to get this set of unknown levels as a python object? Thanks.

When working with `h2o MOJO`s, there is a [java method](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/b2166142527a4961f7cdcd9a96985dbf8cc8019b/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/easy/EasyPredictModelWrapper.java#L199) called `getTotalUnknownCategoricalLevelsSeen()`, but I could not find anything like this in the `h2o python` docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up temporarily capturing the warning output from stderr. Here is the relevant snippet:

```
import contextlib
import StringIO


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stderr_redirect(where):
    """
    Temporarily redirect stdout to a specified python object
    see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197079
    """
    sys.stderr = where
    try:
        yield where
    finally:
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__


# make prediction on data
with stderr_redirect(StringIO.StringIO()) as new_stderr:
    preds = est.predict(frame_in)

print 'Prediction complete'
new_stderr.seek(0)
# capture any warning output
preds_stderr = new_stderr.read()
```

Then used regex to filter to only output lines that contained the column names and list of unseen values, then another regex to filter to get just the list (which I then remove whitespace and `.split(',')` to get a python string `list` of values). Can also use regex to get the column name from same line and pair them in a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider H2O's GLRM (Generalized Low Rank Model).  It can impute missing values.

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glrm.html