# Print formatting a string and function call in python

Tags: python, function, printing

I've got a function, displayHand() which looks like this:

```
def displayHand(hand):
    """
    Displays the letters currently in the hand.

    For example:
    >>> displayHand({'a':1, 'x':2, 'l':3, 'e':1})
    Should print out something like:
       a x x l l l e
    The order of the letters is unimportant.

    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    """
    for letter in hand.keys():
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
             print letter,              # print all on the same line
    print                              # print an empty line
```

It was provided for me (from the 600x class). As described, it takes a dict of string->ints and prints out the "hand".

What I'm having troubles with is getting this to show up properly. When I try

```
print('Current Hand: ', displayHand(hand))
```

This is what I get:

```
a d d m o q y 
('Current Hand: ', None)
```

Since this was provided by the instructor, I'm sure there's a reason the code was written this way and that there's something I'm not getting.

What I'd like to get is output like this:

```
Current Hand: a d d m o q y
```

I'm absolutely brand new to this stuff so I don't even know what questions to ask.

My assessment: As far as I can piece together, displayHand() doesn't return anything and that's what's screwing it all up. But how do I catch the print output of this function and present it the way I want? I was thinking I should try to catch it in a string and have that returned, but assuming

the instructor was trying to demonstrate something, how would I do it without changing the displayHand() method?

If my assessment is off, what's going on?

Edit: This function was given to me by the class, and I'll have to use it as such. I understand changing it to return a str would be much easier, but how could I accomplish the correct output without doing that?

Further Edit: I'm dealing with an autograder that demands the output exactly as I've written. Sorry to be so fussy, I appreciate the answers and would use them if it wasn't for this.

Final Edit: Thanks for the clarification -- I'm going to use your idea and make a helper function inside this function that does what I need it to do!

FINAL final Edit: I figured it out! All I had to do was,

```
print('Current Hand:'),
displayHand(hand)
```

For real final edit:

```
Hah! you got it too! thank you so much for the help, I appreciate it!
```

Comment: I think your function should be returning the values instead of printing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function already prints, it does not return anything.

Don't try to 'catch' the printed output, simply change the function to return the hand, formatted to a string:

```
def displayHand(hand):
    letters = []
    for letter, count in hand.iteritems():
        letters.extend([letter] * count)
    return ' '.join(letters)
```

which gives:

```
>>> hand = {'a': 1, 'q': 1, 'd': 2, 'y': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 1}
>>> displayHand(hand)
'a q d d y m o'
>>> print 'Current Hand:', displayHand(hand)
Current Hand: a q d d y m o
```

If you are not supposed to change the `displayHand()` function, then use the same trick using in the function and do not print a newline by adding a comma to the end of the print statement:

```
print 'Current Hand:',
displayHand(hand)
```

Comment: Hah! I just tried that and ran that exact command through IDLE. However, I need the output to be

    Current Hand: a d v d s v

Comment: @dislikesAppleCores: The original code will *never* write a hand like that. It'd be `a d d v v s` or similar (cards you have multiple of grouped together).

Comment: @dislikesAppleCores: other than that, I fail to see how my code differs from that output.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you must use the provided function and must not try to fix it:

```
print('Current Hand: ', end='')
displayHand(hand)
```

I'm confused, do you use python 2 or 3?

In python 2:

```
print 'Current Hand" ',
displayHand(hand)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `displayHand` function doesn't return anything so when you try to print its result you get `None`. You probably need to remove those `print` statements from the function and return the string instead.

Second, you try to use `print` as a function which is possible obly in python 3 while you seem to be using python 2. If that's the case you need to remove parentheses around the `print` statement arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't modify that function then you might want to redirect the standard output to a string before calling the function and setting it back to normal afterwards.

This post explains how to do it: [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)