# In python, how to do unit test on a function without return value?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have some code like:

```py
class HelloTest:

    def foo(self, msg):
        self.bar(msg.upper())

    def bar(self, msg):
        print(msg)
```

Using the `unittest` standard library, we can use methods like `assertEqual`, `assertTrue` etc. to verify what is returned from a function.

Since `foo` does not return a value explicitly, how can I test that it does the right thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this particular case, I would mock print, then then use the mock in my assertion.

In Python, you will use the [Mock package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) to mock.

Comment: Well, if he is using anything below Python 3 then it's not that simple to mock print. He could mock sys.stdout, but he would have to change bar

Comment: This answer would work if the question was how to test `bar`, but not if we are testing `foo`, since `foo` doesn't call `print`. The functionality of `foo` is to call `bar` with a capitalised message. The answer from @aychedee is correct since it only tests the functionality of `foo`, not `bar`.

Answer (score 21):

As another answer mentioned, you can use the Python mock library to make assertions about calls to functions/methods

```
from mock import patch
from my_module import HelloTest
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('hello.HelloTest.bar')
    def test_foo_case(self, mock_bar):

        ht = HelloTest()

        ht.foo("some string")
        self.assertTrue(mock_bar.called)
        self.assertEqual(mock_bar.call_args[0][0], "SOME STRING")
```

This patches out the `bar` method on HelloTest and replaces it with a mock object that records calls against it.

Mocking is a bit of a rabbit hole. Only do it when you absolutely have to because it does make your tests brittle. You'll never notice an API change for a mocked object for instance.

Comment: in line `self.assertEqual(ob.msg, "SOME STRING")`, where is ob coming from?

Comment: You know... I really don't know? Looks like I made a mistake a 6 years ago :-)
It should be something like:
    `self.assertEqual(mock_bar.call_args[0][0], "SOME STRING")`

I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 19):

I don't quite understand why everybody wants to check that `foo` calls `bar`.

`foo` has some functionality and this functionality needs to be tested. If `foo` is using `bar` to achieve its functionality, it should not be of our concern. We should test that `foo(msg)` writes `msg.upper()` to `sys.stdout`.

You can [redirect `sys.stdout` to a string buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218933/2326961) and check if the content of this buffer matches what you expect.

Example:

```py
import io
import sys
import unittest


class TestScript(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self._old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(), sys.stdout.encoding)

    def test_foo(self):
        hello_test = HelloTest()
        hello_test.foo('hello')
        sys.stdout.seek(0)
        self.assertEqual(sys.stdout.read(), 'HELLO\n')

    def tearDown(self):
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = self._old_stdout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

For a version for which `sys.stdout.write()` accepts both unicode and byte strings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19345047/2326961).

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @Jordan 's introduction, I code this and think it is a workable unit test for HelloTest.foo

```
from mock import Mock
import unittest


class HelloTestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.hello_test = HelloTest()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_foo(self):
        msg = 'hello'
        expected_bar_arg = 'HELLO'
        self.hello_test.bar = Mock()

        self.hello_test.foo(msg)
        self.hello_test.bar.assert_called_once_with(expected_bar_arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 5):

your code can be as given below which does same task as above:

```
class HelloTest(object):

    def foo(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg.upper()
        self.bar()

    def bar(self):
        print self.msg
```

Unit test is :

```
from hello import HelloTest
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo_case(self):
        msg = "test"
        ob = HelloTest()
        ob.foo(msg)
        expected = "TEST"
        self.assertEqual(ob.msg, expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

Comment: This tests *something*. It's not necessarily what needs to be tested, though.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, you can [tell `print` where to print to](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

So add an optional argument:

```
def bar(self, MSG, file=sys.stdout):
    print(MSG, file=file)
```

In normal usage, it will print to stdout, but for unit tests you can pass your own file.

In Python 2 it's a bit messier, but you can [redirect stdout to a StringIO buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer):

```
import StringIO
import sys

out = StringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = out

# run unit tests

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

# check the contents of `out`
```

Comment: Good solution for doing unit test on function with output. But what I care most is how to test `def foo(self, msg)`, since not all function do something with stdout