# Using pytest, how do you test that an input leads to an expected method call, when said method prompts for another input, and is in a continuous loop?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, pytest

[Substituting the built-in input function's value with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests) is often used to test whether a method has the expected response to that input. A tool like monkeypatch would be used to do this, then we'd assert that calling the method returns the expected value.

[Even when you call another method inside the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940389/in-python-how-to-do-unit-test-on-a-function-without-return-value), if the second one has a predictable return value, you can use a similar approach.

Now, what if that method's expected behaviour is to call a method which also asks for input? The aim is to make sure that the program reached that second input prompt (confirming the first input had the expected result). Is there a way to assert this alone?

Example:

```
class TwoInputs:

    def method_a(self):
        self.action = input("Enter something: ")
        if self.action == "jump":
            self.method_b()
            self.method_a()
        elif self.action == "exit":
            quit()

    def method_b(self):
        while True:
            self.action = input("Enter some other thing: ")
            if self.action == "1":
                print("Hello world.")
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input.")
```

In the above context, how would you test that method_a successfully calls method_b, and just end the test there? If I were to monkeypatch input by changing it to "jump", then simply call method_a, that same input would be picked up as invalid in method_b, which then would loop continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if `method_b` has been called, you have to mock it. Also you have to mock `input`, as you mentioned, and make sure it returns values that will lead to the program to ended, and not to a recursion:

```py
@mock.patch("two_inputs.TwoInputs.method_b")
@mock.patch("two_inputs.input")
@mock.patch("two_inputs.quit")
def test_that_a_calls_b(mock_quit, mock_input, mocked_method_b):
    # consecutive call results - second call is from inside `method_a`
    mock_input.side_effect = ["jump", "exit"]
    two_inputs = TwoInputs()
    two_inputs.method_a()
    mocked_method_b.assert_called_once()
```

This assumes that your class lives in `two_inputs.py` at the project root.

For your case, I also added mocking the system function `quit` (otherwise the test would just quit), though I guess you won't call this in your real code.