# How to intercept content of stdout in Python?

Tags: python, django

I make a custom command in Django where make some output to stdout.
How I can intercept stdout make some changes(for example add prefix) and write to stderr?
This is test task so do not pay attention on illogicality of question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `StringIO` like this:

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

print("test")

sys.stdout = old_stdout

s = mystdout.getvalue()
s = "prefix" + s

sys.stderr.write(s)
```

The code is capturing `stdout` into the buffer, then reads the buffer, adds `prefix` and writes to `stderr`.

Also see:

- [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`:

```
from sys import stdout, stderr
output_text = "Some text"
stdout.write('stdout: ' + output_text + '\n')
stderr.write('stderr: ' + output_text + '\n')
```

**Demo:**

```
monty@xonix:~/py$ python so.py &> foo.txt
monty@xonix:~/py$ cat foo.txt
stderr: Some text
stdout: Some text
```