# How to capture ouput from python unittest

Tags: python

I have a python functional test which I am running from another function using:

```
unittest.main(module=ft1.y1, argv=sys.argv[:1], exit=False)
```

I would like to capture the output into a variable.

I've tried

```
out = unittest.main(module=ft1.y1, argv=sys.argv[:1], exit=False)
print 'out ' + str(out)
```

this results in a response of

```
out
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect `sys.stdout` to a string buffer.

See the answers of this question for a couple of ways to do this: [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

Why you run your unit test from another function?
Why you don't use standard runner? For example

```
  class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
      ...
      # tests

  suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTestCase)

  unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

*p.s. I had write this post as answer, because I didn't have enough points to write it as comment.*

Comment: Interesting idea. I've run into a problem discovering the test, so I may post a follow up question - Thanks - Bill