# Trying to capture verbose stdout output with Nose

Tags: python, nose

After running into trouble trying to set the python unittest discover pathway for my project, I'm trying again with nose. I am trying to print out verbose output which is supposedly captured by default by Nose (according to http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/capture.html)

I have:

```
arg =sys.argv[:1]
arg.append('--verbosity=2')
out = nose.run(module=ft1.test_y1, argv=arg)
```

but 'out' is a boolean

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to disable the plugin and capture standard output with some other means, for example as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer):

```
import sys
import nose
from cStringIO import StringIO    

def basic_test():
    print "hello"

if __name__=="__main__":
    module_name = sys.modules[__name__].__file__

    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
    result = nose.run(argv=[sys.argv[0],
                            module_name,
                            '-s'])
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    print mystdout.getvalue()
```

When running it like this you will get:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
hello
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. This helped a lot. The other point is to realize that nose seems to send all its output to STDERR, not STDOUT. As an aside I have to ask : I am confused. Why are you importing Capture if its not used in the code? - Regards, Bill

Comment: No need for Capture - I was trying to see if I could pass an instance of Capture plugin to nose.run() and access it's buffer after the fact, but that did not work. I think the errors in your tests will go into stderr, but a print out will be in stdout. BTW, you can always copy nose plugins to make your own "specialized" plugin that does exactly what you want - it should not be too hard.