# How to capture print output of another module?

Tags: python, stdout

I was wondering if this is possible in python:

```py
# module1
def test():
    print('hey')

# module2
import module1

module1.test() # prints to stdout
```

Without modifying `module1` is there any way to wrap this in `module2` so that I can capture the
`print('hey')` inside a variable? Apart from running `module1` as a script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can.  You need to take control of `sys.stdout`.  Something like this:

```
import sys

stdout_ = sys.stdout #Keep track of the previous value.
sys.stdout = open('myoutputfile.txt', 'w') # Something here that provides a write method.
# calls to print, ie import module1
sys.stdout = stdout_ # restore the previous stdout.
```

Comment: You don't need the first line - you can restore the default stdout by replacing the last line with: `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`

Answer (score 33):

I don't want to be responsible for modifying `sys.stdout` and then restoring it to its previous values. The above answers don't have any `finally:` clause, which can be dangerous integrating this into other important code.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

```
import contextlib, io

f = io.StringIO()
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
    module1.test()
output = f.getvalue()
```

You probably want the variable `output` which is `<class 'str'>` with the redirected stdout.

Note: this code is lifted from the official docs with trivial modifications (but tested). Another version of this answer was already given to a mostly duplicated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434594/1092940

I leave the answer here because it is a much better solution than the others here IMO.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, all you need is to redirect the stdout to a memory buffer that complies with the interface of stdout, you can do it with StringIO. This works for me in 2.7:

```
import sys
import cStringIO


stdout_ = sys.stdout #Keep track of the previous value.
stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = stream
print("hello")  # Here you can do whatever you want, import module1, call test
sys.stdout = stdout_ # restore the previous stdout.
variable = stream.getvalue()  # This will give you the "hello" string inside the variable
```

Comment: This way `sys.stdout.encoding` will be different (after stdout is changed), `stdout` provides more than just `write`

Answer (score 8):

For Python 3:

```
# redirect sys.stdout to a buffer
import sys, io
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = io.StringIO()

# call module that calls print()
import module1
module1.test()

# get output and restore sys.stdout
output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
sys.stdout = stdout

print(output)
```

Answer (score 5):

There's No need to use another module, just class object with write attribute, with one input, which you can save in another variable. for ecample

CLASS:

```
class ExClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.st = ''
    def write(self, o): #here o is the output that goes to stdout
        self.st += str(o)
```

MAIN Program:

```
import sys
stdout_ = sys.stdout
var = ExClass()
sys.stdout = var

print("Hello") # these will not be pronted 
print("Hello2") # instead will be written in var.st

sys.stdout = stdout_

print(var.st)
```

output will be

```
Hello
Hello2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sending ftplib debug output to the logging module

Based on the approach taken by `jimmy kumar ahalpara` answer, I was able to capture `ftplib`'s debug output into `logging`. ftplib was around before the logging module and uses `print` to emit debug messages.

I'd tried reassigning the print function to a logging method but I couldn't get that to work. The code below works for me.

I should think this will work with other modules as well but there would not be any granularity between different module's output as it's capturing everything sent to `stdout` to the same logger.

```
# convenience class to redirect stdout to logging
class SendToLog: 
    def __init__(self, logging_method): 
        self.logger = logging _method
    def write(self, o): 
        if str(o).strip():  #  ignore empty lines
            self.logger(str(o))


import logging
import sys

# code to initialise logging output and handlers ...
# ...

# get logger for ftplib and redirect it's print output to our log
ftp_logger = logging.getLogger('ftplib')
# note: logging's debug method is passed to the class, the instance then calls this method
sys.stdout = SendToLog(ftp_logger.debug)

# code to do stuff with ftplib ...
# remember to set ftplib's debug level > 0 or there will be no output
# FTP.set_debuglevel(1)
# ...

# important to finalise logging and restore stdout
logging.shutdown()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

[python3](/questions/tagged/python3) [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout) [ftplib](/questions/tagged/ftplib) [logging](/questions/tagged/logging)