# How can I suppress stdout logging output for a module I'm importing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, stdout

I'm importing a module `foo` which uses Python's `logging` module. However, `foo` produces a huge amount of logging output, and I need to use `stdout` to communicate important information to the user, which is largely being drowned out by the ridiculous output of the module I'm importing.

How can I disable the module's ability to log to `stdout` without modifying `foo`'s code? I still want it to log to the files it logs to, but I don't want it logging to `stdout`.

I have tried the following:

`logging.getLogger("foo").propagate = False`

and

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def nostdout():
    class DummyFile(object):
        def write(self, x): pass
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = DummyFile()
    yield
    sys.stdout = save_stdout

with nostdout(): import foo
```

Comment: Does module `foo` configure the logging itself? If it is a library it should not. Then you can simply configure logging to go to a file instead of stdout.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#module-logging.config

Comment: It is a library. Sadly all libraries are not well-written, and this one does configure the logging itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
logging.getLogger(<logger_name_used_in_foo>).propagate = False
```

Comment: What kind of library are you using?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's a data retrieval module.

Comment: I've updated my answer. What is the name of the logger which is used in the "foo" module?

Comment: For those who want know the name of all  the loggers from an existing log object, you can use log.manager.loggerDict which is a dictionary of all the registered log handlers.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm referencing this article.](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/)
In general, if you want to capture anything written to `stdout` you can use the `contextlib` in Python 3:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    print('foobar')
    call_annoying_module()
print('Stdout: "{0}"'.format(f.getvalue()))
```

On Python 3.4 and older, `redirect_stdout` can be implemented like this:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirector(stream):
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = stream
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

If the library has any C bindings that print using `puts` then it gets more complicated. See the article.

The easiest case is when you're running another program using `subprocess`,
then all `stdout` output can be easily captured.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("echo output".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
std_output, err_output = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but a previous user posted something similar to this (using a context manager and manually redirecting stdout to a dummy file), but that didn't work.

Comment: I see. If all else fails and if it's possible to call the module as a separate program, see my recent edit at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Oh, sorry, using Python2.7 so this doesn't work generally.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your subprocess example works. I need to be able to use objects from the module I'm importing.

Comment: Ok, nevermind the subprocess example. On Python 2 you can implement redirect_stdout on your own. See edits.

Comment: I did that -- that's the solution I was referencing that didn't work.

Comment: Specifically it was `def nostdout(): save_stdout = sys.stdout; sys.stdout = DummyFile(); yield; sys.stdout = save_stdout` with DummyFile() being a class that implemented an empty `write` method.

Comment: Obviously with a `@contextlib.contextmanager` flag... I'll add this to the OP so this is clear.

Comment: I see. You can also try to do it without decorators by reassigning stdout as needed. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822267/python-capture-print-output-of-another-module)

Comment: It's a proprietary library. I have the source code. Based on your last comment, I logged stdout to file. Interestingly but perhaps unsurprisingly, it isn't outputting the text that I'm trying to get rid of, so somehow it is putting text to stdout without Python being aware of it. Unclear if that makes sense.

Comment: Basically it is outputting things to stdout that aren't outputted to a file when I redirect stdout to that file.

Comment: Even doing logging.shutdown() doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: [Maybe use the pdb to detect when stdout is changed?](http://sourceforge.net/blog/watchpoints-in-python/)

Comment: I'll try that when I get back the office. Honestly at this point I'm considering just patching the library myself since it's clearing doing something odd.