# How do I make an eval command in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that is limited to me and a few friends. I want to make an eval command so I can show off to them since they know nothing about code, but also for me to use in general (I have a permissions system setup so it's usage is limited to me, don't worry).

I've done a lot of googling and the closest I've gotten is this:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def eval(self, ctx, *, args):
    result = eval(args)
    await ctx.send(result)
```

This doesn't work with multi-line code though. For example, I tried this code:

```
&eval a=2
b=2
c=a*b
print(str(a), str(b), str(c))
```

It returns this error: `Invalid syntax` and points to `a=2` as the error. With other solutions like the ones from the creator's github, it said that `eval() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I'm using the commands extension and the `eval` command will be in a cog. Thanks!

Comment: Saying "doesn't work" it's not really helpful for us, it's too broad. Please edit the question and add any tracebacks/errors, output issues, the result, the expected result...

Comment: edited to include errors, sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

The [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function is supposed to execute only one expression, for dynamic execution use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

```py
>>> code = """
... a = 2
... b = 2
... c = a * b
... print(a, b, c)
... """
>>> exec(code)
2 2 4
```

You can also use `aioconsole.aexec` for a non-blocking way

```py
>>> from aioconsole import aexec
>>> 
>>> code = """
... a = 2
... b = 2
... c = a * b
... print(a, b, c)
... """
>>> await aexec(code) # It should be awaited inside another coroutine, not doing so for explanation purposes
2 2 4
```

[`aioconsole` pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/aioconsole/)

Comment: For both methods, it calls an error labelled `cannot send an empty message`. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, the value you're getting is `None`, neither `exec` and `aexec` return any values, you shouldn't assign them to a variable, there are a couple of ways of catching the output from the console, for more info refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621134/python-pss-e-get-output-as-variable