# How can I pipe a Python process' output in Python?

Tags: python, pipe, piping, youtube-dl

I'm writing a program that downloads videos from YouTube, using [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

I used to call youtube-dl with `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen([command], \
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, \
    universal_newlines = True)
```

Then, I would read the process' output by calling:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ""):
    hide_some_stuff_using_regex()
    show_some_stuff_using_regex()
```

However, I prefer using `youtube-dl` as a Python class. So I'm now doing this:

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL as youtube_dl

options = {"restrictfilenames": True, \
           "progress_with_newline": True}

ydl = youtube_dl(options)
ydl.download([url])
```

The code works, but I'm having a hard time finding out, how to pipe `youtube-dl`'s output. Note that I want to use parts of youtube-dl's output to print in real-time, so redirecting `sys.stdout` to a custom output stream will not work, as I still need sys.stdout to print.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is `youtube_dl`?

Comment: Good catch, updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for youtube-dl, you can set a logger object, like in the [advanced example](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) in the documentation:

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL


class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        print('debug information: %r' % msg)

    def warning(self, msg):
        print('warning: %r' % msg)

    def error(self, msg):
        print('error: %r' % msg)


options = {
    "restrictfilenames": True,
    "progress_with_newline": True,
    "logger": MyLogger(),
}

url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'
with YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

Comment: Beautiful. Great to be able to be in contact with the developer himself!

Comment: What about getting ffmpeg info? I'd like to grab the the `frame= 1766 fps=157 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10152kB time=00:01:13.66 bitrate=1128.9kbits/s speed=6.54x` line

Answer (score 1):

You can try to redirect sys.stdout to your own output stream
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218951/2134702

---

To quote the linked answer:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

# blah blah lots of code ...

sys.stdout = old_stdout

# examine mystdout.getvalue()
```

And if you want to output to stdout
during the redirection, instead of print use old_stdout.write()

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I thought about that, but from the moment I redirect `sys.stdout` to an output stream, I'm not able to use print anymore, am I? The print statements would be redirected to the output stream and not get printed on my screen. That's a problem, because I want to print some parts of youtube-dl's output on my screen in real-time.

Comment: @Exeleration-G, if you save the stdout stream (as shown in the linked answer), you can write to it (instead of using print command), and it would be printed to the main screen in real time.

Comment: @Eran: Of course! I didn't think of using stuff like `old_stdout.write()`!