# Python Internally Buffered Output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like some way to `print()` to a string or internal buffer rather than stdout in Python.

Ideally, I could print to this and later dump the string to the console just as if it had been printed to stdout to begin with. Something like:

```
>>> print("output 1", a)
>>> print("output 2", a)
>>> print(a)
output 1
output 2
```

If you're wondering, I'm doing this for the sake of quick refactoring on code that previously printed directly to the console.

Comment: you want to use print to store it to variable instead of displaying it to console???

Comment: You want to redirect `stdout`. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer

Comment: you can also just use a normal file and seek before printing without needing an import

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module.

You simply use it that way :

```
import StringIO

a= StringIO.StringIO()
a.write('output 1\n')
print >>a, 'output 2'

# Retrieve file contents -- this will be
# 'output 1\noutput 2\n'
contents = a.getvalue()

# Close object and discard memory buffer --
# .getvalue() will now raise an exception.
a.close()

# will output 'output 1\noutput 2\n'
print contents
```

EDIT : I had not seen Josh's answer before posting mine. His syntax is for python 3 mine is for older python 2.x

Comment: I missed the "answer your own question" checkbox, my bad.

Comment: printing `a` would print `StringIO.StringIO instance at ...`

Answer (score 0):

`StringIO` acts like a virtual file and can be used for this purpose, but you must be careful to get the behavior you described:

```
>>> import io
>>> a = io.StringIO('')
>>> print("output 1", file=a)
>>> print("output 2", file=a)
>>> print(a.getvalue())  # notice the extra new line at the end...
output 1
output 2

>>> print(a.getvalue(), end='')  # use end='' to suppress extra new line
output 1
output 2
>>> print(a)  # print(a) will not yield the same results
<_io.StringIO object at 0x7fe3a23568b8>
>>> print("output 3", a)  # make sure to use "file=", or it will print str(a)!
output 3 <_io.StringIO object at 0x7fe3a23568b8>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) method takes a seldom-used parameter, `file`, which simply has to be a 'file-like' (it defaults to stdout). From the doc:

> The file argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method; if it is not present or None, sys.stdout will be used. Output buffering is determined by file. Use `file.flush()` to ensure, for instance, immediate appearance on a screen.

You could provide your own buffering implementation or use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) as the file-like if you wanted to maintain the `print` syntax.