# Print information to a text box in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I want to make a menu with a message box (or self filling text box) and some buttons.

This message box must contain the printed output from another py program.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wm10oi72ytpb3p8/main_menu.py?dl=0) is my code on Dropbox.

The printed output is in this code: [Wunderground_info](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rpongfpjkic2zo/wunderground_basic.py?dl=0)

Who could help me with this problem?

Comment: You should just add the code to your question. And when you say menu, do you mean a top bar menu? Or is the menu a part of your actual window? If your display text, use a label, and you Tkinter's `StringVar()` to store it.

Comment: What is your specific question? What part of the problem do you need help with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you really should add both code and output to the question --- it will not only make this question easier to answer, but also will provide lasting value --- as other people with similar problems will be able to find it easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to get the output from `stdout`, then you probably need to temporarily redirect it. See: [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)
Then, once you have that output in a string , it should be straightforward to create a frame with it:

```
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText
import Tkinter as tk

class OutputViewer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, data, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.text = ScrolledText(self, width=90, height=13)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.insert(tk.END, data)
        self.text.see(tk.END)
```

Hope that helps.