# Programmatic ansible: save result into python variable

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-api

I am using this code to run ansible programmatically: https://github.com/jtyr/ansible-run_playbook with a simple playbook that just gathers facts from an Ubuntu server and prints them to the screen:

```
- name: Test play
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Debug task
      debug:
        msg: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]}}"
      tags:
        - debug
```

But what I really need is to simply save that output into a python variable instead of running it through a template or outputting to the screen (I will actually be using it inside of a Django app). Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output was always going to stdout. The `Runner` class has no way to change this behavior. I got an idea from [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer) The following change will save the output in `mystdout`. You can access the output by calling `mystdout.getvalue()`

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

def main():
    runner = Runner(
    ...
        # vault_pass='vault_password',
    )

    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

    stats = runner.run()

    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    print mystdout.getvalue()
```