# Pandas CParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large csv file with 25 columns, that I want to read as a pandas dataframe. I am using `pandas.read_csv()`. 
The problem is that some rows have extra columns, something like that:

```
        col1   col2   stringColumn   ...   col25
1        12      1       str1                 3
...
33657    2       3       str4                 6       4    3 #<- that line has a problem
33658    1      32       blbla                 #<-some columns have missing data too
```

When I try to read it, I get the error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 25 fields in line 33657, saw 28
```

The problem does not happen if the extra values appear in the first rows. For example if I add values to the third row of the same file it works fine

```
#that example works: 
           col1   col2   stringColumn   ...   col25
    1        12      1       str1                 3
    2        12      1       str1                 3
    3        12      1       str1                 3       f    4
    ...
    33657    2       3       str4                 6       4    3 #<- that line has a problem
    33658    1      32       blbla                 #<-some columns have missing data too
```

My guess is that pandas checks the first (n) rows to determine the number of columns, and if you have extra columns after that it has a problem parsing it.

Skipping the offending lines like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data) is not an option, those lines contain valuable information.

Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: How do you expect those lines to be stored and represented? For instance are you after 25 or 28 columns?

Comment: I am only interested in about half of the 25 columns. The values in the extra column do not interest me.

Comment: Are the number of columns fixed or not? i.e. is it always 28

Comment: Could you not just do `pd.read_csv(file_path, delim_whitespace=True, usecols=np.arange(25))`?

Comment: I tried `data = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=2, delimiter="\t", dtype='str', 
                               index_col=0, usecols=np.arange(25))` and got `ValueError: Usecols do not match names`. (the fields are separeted by \t and there is one extra line at the beginning, therefore the arguments `skiprows` and `delimiter`

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find an answer that completely solves the problem, here is my work around: I found out that explicitly passing the column names with the option `names=('col1', 'col2', 'stringColumn' ... 'column25', '', '', '')` allows me to read the file. It forces me to read and parse every column, which is not ideal since I only need about half of them, but at least I can read the file now. 
Combinining the arguments `names` and  `usecols` and does not work, if somebody has another solution I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

In my initial post I mentioned not using "error_bad_lines" = False in pandas.read_csv.  I decided that actually doing so is the more proper and elegant solution.  I found this post quite useful.

[Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

I added a little twist to the code shown in the answer.

```
import sys
import re
from cStringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

fake_csv = '''1,2,3\na,b,c\na,b,c\na,b,c,d,e\na,b,c\na,b,c,d,e\na,b,c\n''' #bad data
fname = "fake.csv"
old_stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = mystderr = StringIO()

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fake_csv),
                  error_bad_lines=False)

sys.stderr = old_stderr 
log = mystderr.getvalue()
isnum = re.compile("\d+")

lines_skipped_log = [
    isnum.findall(i) + [fname]\
    for i in log.split("\n") if isnum.search(i)
        ]

columns=["line_num","flds_expct","num_fields","file"]
lines_skipped_log.insert(0,columns)
```

From there you can do anything you want with `lines_skipped_log` such as output to csv, create a dataframe etc.

Perhaps you have a directory full of files.  You can create a list of pandas data frames out of each log and concatenate.  From there you will have a log of what rows were skipped and for which files at your fingertips (literally!).

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to specify the column names. Please refer my answer to a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43145539/6466550