# Asserting a function that prints an array

Tags: python, arrays, assert, assertion

I am trying to test this function

```
def print_board(M):
    for i in range (M.shape[0]):
        line=''
        for j in range (M.shape[1]):
           line+=str(int(M[i,j]))
        print(line)
```

I created a new file to test it and imported my file and the function array but I am not too sure on how I can test it since I don't return it, I tried this :

```
assert(print_board(array([[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]],dtype='bool')) == '''111 000 111''')
```

but got

> AssertionError

Comment: His function is quite too difficult for me to understand the answers that was given to him for me to apply it to myself, sorry.

Comment: Your guess is correct; since print_board has no `return` statement, the return value is Python's `None' value.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is redirect Python standard output (where print sends it) to a string, and then compare that string.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218933/2800918) for an explanation of how to do that.

Comment: thanks I'll try that