# Python: Revert sys.stdout to default

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I wanted to write output to file and hence I did

```
sys.stdout = open(outfile, 'w+')
```

But then I wanted to print back to console after writing to file

```
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = None
```

And I got

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Obviously the default output stream can't be `None`, **so how do I say to Python**:

```
sys.stdout = use_the_default_one()
```

Comment: one way is to store it as `default_sysout` before assigning to `outfile` and then assign it back using `default_sysout` after outfile is closed, but just in case I didn't where can I get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can revert to the original stream by reassigning to `sys.__stdout__`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__)

> contain[s] the original values of stdin, stderr and stdout at the start of the program. They are used during finalization, and could be useful to print to the actual standard stream no matter if the sys.std* object has been redirected.

The [redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager may be used instead of manually reassigning:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(myoutputfile):
    print(output)
```

(there is a similar [redirect_stderr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr))

Changing `sys.stdout` has a global effect.  This may be undesirable in multi-threaded environments, for example.  It might also be considered as over-engineering in simple scripts.  A localised, alternative approach would be to pass the output stream to [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) via its `file` keyword argument:

```
print(output, file=myoutputfile)
```

Comment: `sys.__stdout__`: that's exactly what I was looking for. One less variable in my code :) Yeyy!

Answer (score 6):

In Python3 use [redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout); a similar case is given as an example:

> To send the output of help() to a file on disk, redirect the output to
>   a regular file:

```
with open('help.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        help(pow)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer) you don't need to save a reference to the old stdout. Just use sys.__stdout__.

Also, you might consider using `with open('filename.txt', 'w+') as f` and using `f.write` instead.

Comment: Thanks but I want all the warnings and other print statements to print it to the file.