# python sys.__stdout__ is equal to None by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, sys

The problem is simple. I copied an example from a Python book about output redirection and firstly `sys.stdout` is changed to a file object and then is restored to `sys.__stdout__`.
However the restoration part doesn't seem to work because the output later in the code doesn't get displayed at all anywhere.

I found out the issue which I'll explain with this shell code sample:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout
<idlelib.run.StdOutputFile object at 0x00000191D0BCFB50>
>>> sys.__stdout__
>>> print(sys.__stdout__)
None
>>>
```

So: why is `sys.__stdout__` equal to `None` by default?

EDIT: I know about the context manager in contextlib explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340347/python-revert-sys-stdout-to-default) issue but I still would like to know why this happens.

Comment: As a note, `idle` on my ubuntu linux system has `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that you're using an OS environment where `sys.stdout` is not normally set with an initial value. Two relevant portions of the documentation are quoted below (bolded emphasis mine):

From the [IDLE documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#running-user-code):

> By default, IDLE runs user code in a separate OS process rather than in the user interface process that runs the shell and editor. In the execution process, it replaces `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr` with objects that get input from and send output to the Shell window. **The original values stored in `sys.__stdin__`, `sys.__stdout__`, and `sys.__stderr__` are not touched**, but may be `None`.

From the [`sys` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__):

> Under some conditions `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` as well as the original values `__stdin__`, `__stdout__` and `__stderr__` can be `None`. **It is usually the case for Windows GUI apps that aren’t connected to a console and Python apps started with pythonw**.

Under these conditions, IDLE is setting a value for `sys.stdout` when the initial values for `sys.stdout` and `sys.__stdout__` were `None`.

If this is problematic for the environment you're using, you can always save the initial value of `sys.stdout` and restore it later.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__):

> Under some conditions stdin, stdout and stderr as well as the
> original values `__stdin__`, `__stdout__` and `__stderr__` can be None. **It
> is usually the case for Windows GUI apps that aren’t connected to a
> console** and Python apps started with pythonw.

You're using IDLE, which does not bind `__stdout__` as it's a GUI app. It overrides `sys.stdout` to the IDLE default `stdout` stream.