# Saving the result of print function as a figure

Tags: python-3.x, stanford-nlp

I use Stanford coreNLP for generating dependency tree, but I cannot store the result as it uses print function to show the tree. For instance, the code and the dependency tree for "I ask a question in StackOverFlow" would be like this:

```
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('.')
parser=nlp.parse("I ask a question in StackOverFlow") 
tree=Tree.fromstring(parser.__str__()) 
tree.pretty_print()
```

[image]

Here I used Snipping Tool to take a screenshot of the generated tree manually, but in my code I will generate more than thousand trees, which is impossible to take screenshots from all of them. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to redirect `stdout`. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I redirect the stdout in python into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

On a UNIX-based system you can do:

`parse.py`

```
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('.')
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    sentence = sentences[i]
    parser=nlp.parse(sentence) 
    tree=Tree.fromstring(parser.__str__())
    print(i, sentence)
    print('parse tree:')
    tree.pretty_print()
    print()
```

and do sth like `python parse.py > parse_trees` and your output file `parse_trees` will be structured as:

```
[index] [sentence]
parse tree:
[parse tree]

[index] [sentence]
parse tree:
[parse tree]

...
```