# Executing AWS CLI using python

Tags: aws-cli

While Executing AWS CLI using python, Please find code for reference.

```
import awscli.clidriver
driver = awscli.clidriver.create_clidriver()
driver.main(['ec2','describe-instances','--instance-ids','i-12345678'])
```

Is it possible to store the output of driver.main in a variable ?

Comment: Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to execute aws cli using python, While executing it using above method its returning the output of describe instance on CLI, I am not able to store the retrieved output in variable, whereas I am able to store exit code of executed cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is supported by the AWS CLI but you can do this:

```py
import awscli.clidriver
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

driver = awscli.clidriver.create_clidriver()

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

driver.main(['ec2','describe-instances','--instance-ids','i-12345678'])

sys.stdout = old_stdout

myvar = mystdout.getvalue()
```

Note that this is based on another Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218951/3787051).

Comment: Thanks for help.
yes its returning the expected outcome, but result is string and is not convertible to json using json library of python.

Comment: Of course it is convertible to JSON. Just add lines `import json ; myjson = json.loads(myvar)`.

Comment: @SakshiGupta, if this helped you should accept the correct answer.

Comment: It did help Thanks :)