# Get output of a function as string

Tags: python

I have a function that prints. How to get its output to string?
Note: **I cant change the function code.**

```py
def f():
    print('hello world')

# do something

assert x == 'hello world\n'
```

I need this because spark dataframe has method `explain` that **prints** info about execution plan. But I need this info **as string** in my program.

```
>>> df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Scan ExistingRDD[age#0,name#1]
```

Comment: change the `print` to a `return`?

Comment: I cant change the function

Comment: You can redirect stdout. This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434594/4204843

```py
def f():
    print('hello world')

import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with io.StringIO() as buf, redirect_stdout(buf):
    f()
    x = buf.getvalue()

assert x == 'hello world\n'
```