# Find previous character in console in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, printf

Is there a way to find the previous character(s) in the console in python?

```
print('Hello', end='')
```

should return `'o'`.

If there is a way to do this, how can I get the previous x characters? e.g. `'lo'` if I want 2 characters. Should also work for tracebacks.

Comment: There's no clean way to get back data you sent to the stdout stream. However, you can redirect stdout to string that you can inspect later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer

Comment: Standard output is an _output_, not an input. Unless you're just trying to do some logging or record a run of something, that content is too late to work with at that point. If you wanted to work with `'Hello'`, you should save it to a variable with e.g. `my_string = 'Hello'`. If you want to work with the text of tracebacks, you can catch the exception and save it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `subprocess` and PIPE your output of the script you are running.
Ex:
You want to get console output from:

```
#script1.py
print('Hello',end='')
```

Creating a subprocess will let you run and get the STDOUT & STDERR

```
#subproc.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
process = Popen(['python','script1.py'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
stdout,stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout.decode('utf-8')) #console output
print(stderr.decode('utf-8')) #traceback, empty if there's no error

#From there you can manipulate string
print(stdout.decode('utf-8')[-1:]) #will print string 'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need something similar that what Expect does.

Check this code:

```
import pty
import os

my_list_accumulator = []

def read_stuff(fd):
    output = os.read(fd, 1024)
    my_list_accumulator.append(output)
    return output

pty.spawn('python3', read_stuff)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pty
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> my_list_accumulator = []
>>> 
>>> def read_stuff(fd):
...     output = os.read(fd, 1024)
...     my_list_accumulator.append(output)
...     return output
...     
... 
>>> pty.spawn('python3', read_stuff)
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2020, 14:04:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('Hello', end='')
Hello>>> And this will give error
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    And this will give error
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
0
>>> # pressed Ctrl-D to escape
... 
>>> print(b''.join(my_list_accumulator).decode('utf-8'))
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2020, 14:04:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('Hello', end='')
Hello>>> And this will give error
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    And this will give error
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 

>>>
```

So, you can modify the `read_stuff` function to do what you wish, but make sure to read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html