# Redirecting print to variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to redirect some of the prints in a module, specifically [keras-tuner](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner), to a variable. It seems that there might be a similar solution: [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

class Capturing(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self._stringio = StringIO()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
        del self._stringio    # free up some memory
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
```

Then I wrapped around my code that has a module that prints, for example [search_space_summary](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/master/kerastuner/engine/base_tuner.py)

```
with Capturing() as output:
    model_info["tuner"].search_space_summary()
```

However upon inspection there is nothing in `output`. But one can simply do a `print("Hello")` and it is captured in `output`, but not this function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I checked both stdout and stderr, but they are both empty. I might be wrong, but looking at the `patch` block, it seems that they are testing the output should be empty?

Comment: Interesting. At a glance, particularly reading [the definition of `search_space_summary`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/c23537d4bddd6cefb73b53d88dacaad1b48fc06f/kerastuner/engine/base_tuner.py#L266-L280) -- which is just doing plain `print` calls -- this _looks_ like it should work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy All of the print statements in this module are not capture-able, very strange

Comment: ...I do notice that `from __future__ import print_function` is in use. Be interesting to look into just how that's implemented (if the Python runtime version in question is one where it isn't just a noop). On which point -- which runtime version _is_ this observed with?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using python 3.7.7

Answer (score 0):

The keras-tuner package's [util.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/master/kerastuner/utils.py) includes IPython/Jupyter notebook magic that displays custom output if a user is using a notebook and does not use the print function.

Hence there was not output.