# Pytest: How can I blindly run any subprocess and capture all output?

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

I have a Python program that calls `print()` and/or calls `subprocess.Popen()` on scripts in several other languages, which can also `print, console.log, system.out.println,` etc. The actual program easily prints all of this to the terminal, which is the intended behavior.

For integration testing, I want to capture all of this output to check if it matches an expected value. I *cannot* mock the subprocess. This is *not* unit testing, I don't care what my Python code is actually doing, only that the output is correct.

All of these options work for capturing the internal Python output:

- [Use the `capfd` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/capture.html) to capture and read all output directly with Pytest
- [Use `context_lib` and `redirect_stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434594/8412474)
- Reassign `sys.stdout` manually to an explicit file, then read this file to get output

Here's roughly what the code looks like. For `capfd` and `redirect_stdout` you just shift around what you do right before and right after `run_string`.

```
# tests are parametrized from several JSON files.
def test_code(test_json):
    with open("/tmp/output_file.txt", "w+") as output_file:
        orig_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = output_file
        print("initial")
        run_string(test_json["code"])
        output_file.seek(0)
        sys.stdout = orig_stdout
        output = output_file.read()
        assert output == test_json["expected"]
```

These all get the internal output perfectly, but all *fail* to get consistent output from `subprocess.Popen`. I have tried using all of these methods, setting `subprocess.stdout` to a file, to `PIPE` and printing it back out later, `shell=True`, and a few other things, but they all have the same strange issues. I really have no explanation for any of this behavior, so I'm just hoping someone can help me:

- All of this code works fine when I actually run my code using its CLI.
- The JavaScript subprocess always works, it's output is captured correctly, no matter which method I use.
- The Python subprocess *does* work when I use VSCode integrated test debugging, but *not* when I run `pytest` from the command line. Huh? Why?!?!?!?
- The Lua subprocess hangs entirely. It appears the subprocess never actually starts, although it's very hard to tell what's going on since I can't debug from Python into Lua, and I can't just print things out because Pytest is trying to capture everything.
- I've only added these 3 languages so far, but I intend to add many more (and in theory, all of them) so I'm hoping for a generic solution.

I could also try testing the entire CLI, but I'd like to avoid that, and I'm not sure it would work anyway. If anyone knows a way to force Pytest to run exactly like the native code does without putting subprocesses in some kind of box, that's really what I need.

Comment: What do you mean  by "fail to get *consistent* output from `subprocess.Popen`"? Does a given test sometimes work and sometimes fail? Are you sometines getting corrupt output? Can you post runnable example code that will reliably reproduce the problem you're describing?

Comment: If it's not unit testing, run your app in a subprocess, capture the stdout and verify it after the app finishes.

Comment: The output is consistent between runs, sorry for the confusion. It's only inconsistent based on which subprocess I am calling, as in, JavaScript works, Lua doesn't, and Python is somewhere in the middle. I am coming around to running my entire app in a subprocess. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I eventually settled on the `capfd` hook, and removed the nested subprocess requirement entirely. The subprocesses my app needs to execute are no longer allowed to output directly to shell, specifically because it is so inconsistent. This is the final code I ended up with.

```py
def test_dits(dit_json, capfd):
    if "long" in dit_json and not pytest.all_val:  # type: ignore
        pytest.skip("Long test")
    run_string(dit_json["dit"], "tests/fail.dit")
    output, err = capfd.readouterr()

    assert output == dit_json["expected"]
```

Comment: If this is a solution that solves your problem, you should mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but for anyone doing something similar, remember to pass "`capture_output=True`" if you are using `subprocess.run( )` in your pytest test.

```
args = ['sqldiff', '--summary', file_path_1, file_path_2]
completed_process = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True)
assert completed_process.returncode == 0
sqldiff_stdout_lines = completed_process.stdout.decode('ascii').split('\n')
```

If you do that, then the return object will include the `stdout` data from the subprocess.  See the [Python stdlib subprocess docs for more info...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)