# Is there a way I can run code that is printed by a function in python?

Tags: python

For example, say I have a function like

```
def example():
    print("print('Hello')\nprint('There')")
```

Is there a way I can run the text outputted without having to run the function, copy the output and rerun the output?

Comment: This part is not clear: "*without having to run the function*". The string is hardcoded inside the `print(...)`. You want to get that string without _calling_ the function?

Comment: You could set `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` stream. Then you can call the function, get the contents of the stream, and call `exec()`

Comment: @GinoMempin I think he means without having to copy and paste it from the terminal output.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/478746). Could you comment what your use case is for printing Python code to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

See [Can I redirect the stdout into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer) for many ways to capture standard output in a string variable.

Use that when calling the function, then use `exec(variable)` to execute the output.

Comment: Thanks! Exec() is exactly what I was looking for.