# Color the prints of function passed as an argument

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def executor(f):
    print("This is executor")
    f()

def demo():
    print("This is demo function")

executor(demo)
```

Is there any way to color the output of `demo` function from `executor` function without modifying the original function?

Comment: Well since you are using executor to call `f` and you are doing nothing with variables directly, no. Also printing colored text in the console is platform specific(ish): https://stackoverflow.com/a/287944/8382028

Comment: @ViaTech can I modify `f` before calling it, to add color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of one way to do this, but it's pretty janky, and might break stuff in fun and unexpected ways : you could redirect `stdout`, as was shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218933/21688300).
Once you've done that, you can retrieve whatever was printed during the time stdout was redirected, color it, and print it to your terminal using the **termcolor** package (suggested in the [question referenced in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287871/21688300)).

In code, that would be something like the following :

```py
import io
import sys

import termcolor


def executor(f):
    print("This is executor")
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    buffer = io.StringIO()

    # wrap in a try - finally, bc we really don't want
    # to be left without a stdout if this fails
    try:
        sys.stdout = buffer
        f()
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout

    termcolor.cprint(buffer.getvalue(), "green")


def demo():
    print("This is demo function")


executor(demo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI Code in python3.x.

```
print("\033[91m{0},{1}\033[00m".format("hello", "world"))
```

[image]

Refer to [ANSI escape code: Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

- `\033[`: This is an escape code, which is a way of producing non-printable characters such as color codes.
- `91m`: This is a color code that represents the color red in the terminal.
- `{0},{1}`: These are placeholders for the format() method. {0} is replaced by the first argument passed to format(), and {1} is replaced by the second argument passed to format().
- `\033[00m`: This resets the color back to the terminal's default color.
- `.format("hello", "world")`: This is a method which formats the string by replacing {0} and {1} with "hello" and "world" respectively.